# How many ways can an ordered set of letters be arranged in N positions

Tags: combinatorics

If I have the letters X Y Y X, how many times can I place them in 12 positions: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _,
while preserving the order, i.e. the Ys must be between the Xs but there can be other characters interspersed, i.e. abXcYdYefgXh would be a valid combination.

I thought the answer would simply be $12 \choose 4$, but my friend disagrees.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which letters can be placed in the remaining eight positions?

Comment: Any letters other than X an Y can be placed in the remaining positions.

Comment: Are you making a distinction between abXcYdYefgXh and zbXcYdYefgXh? If not, then my answer should suffice. If so, then which letters can be in the remaining positions? Can there be more Xs and Ys? If so, then it is $26^8\cdot\binom{12}{4}$. If the letters can be anything but X or Y, then it is $24^8\cdot\binom{12}{4}$.

Comment: The letters can be anything but X or Y, so the second answer applies

Answer (score 0):

Think of instead choosing the positions for the other $8$ letters. Then in the remaining $4$ spaces you must put an X then a Y then another Y then the other X. Since $\binom{12}{4}=\binom{12}{8}$, you are correct.

Comment: If other letters can be placed in the remaining eight positions, your answer is not correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, the original question was how many unique ways can you place the Xs and Ys and in that case my answer was correct. since then the question has been altered.

Comment: After you wrote your last comment, the OP indicated that any letter other than X or Y can be placed in the remaining eight positions.